# How to filter objects based on different keys and save the results into an array

Tags: javascript, object

I want to filter object based on key

```
var form = { code_ 1 : "C", 
             option_1 : "1321", 
             code_ 2 : "A", 
             option_2 : "1521", 
             code_ 3 : "B", 
             option_3 : "1121", 
             ...
           }
```

I want filter object and save into array.

```
code = ["C", "A", "B"]
option = ["1321", "1521", "1121"]
```

but I don't how because there is a number in the attribute name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Object.entries to transform the `form` to array of key-value pairs

After that, iterate through the pair, check the key string and push the value to the propriated array

```js
const code = [];
const option = [];

var form = {
  code_1: "C",
  option_1: "1321",
  code_2: "A",
  option_2: "1521",
  code_3: "B",
  option_3: "1121",
};

Object.entries(form).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  if (key.startsWith("code")) {
    code.push(value);
  } else if (key.startsWith("option")) {
    option.push(value);
  }
});

console.log({
  code,
  option,
});
```